# Matching strings with square brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input list such as this that I am reading in:

```
MyList = ["BUS_A[0]", "BUS_A[1]", "BUS_A[2]", "BUS_B[0]", "PORTA", "PORTB"]
```

I have a yaml of regexes that I am reading in that looks like this:

```
regex:  
- BUS_A[0]  
- BUS_A[2]  
- PORTB
```

I want to filter out the regexes in yaml from the List.

So first I read the Yaml file that has the regexes:

```
with open(options.ExcludeYaml, 'r') as InYaml:  
    ReadFullYaml = yaml.safe_load(InYaml)  
Ports =    ReadFullYaml["regex"]
```

And then I compile the regex:

```
MyPattern = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(Ports))
```

And then I iterate through the list to filter out the matches:

```
for i in MyList:  
    if re.match(MyPattern, i):
        print (i)
```

However, when I run the code it only matches PORTB:

```
csh> temp.py -m temp.yaml  
csh> PORTB
```

I tried updating the regex in yaml to BUS_A\[0\] and BUS_A\\[0\\] but it doesn't work. Any idea what I am doing wrong with the regex? How do I get to match the strings with square brackets?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(Ports)` produce? If we could see the string we could help you more easily.

Comment: as you match full strings exactly, why don't you just do `if MyPattern == i`? just asking in case you are a beginner who for some reason thinks that regex is the only way to compare strings. ofc there are cases where regexes are useful, but the code you posted does not seem like one.

Comment: Ken, here is the output of print (MyPattern.pattern):

\b(?:BUS_A[0]|BUS_A[2]|PORTB)\b

Comment: Antont, I do have some regexes in the yaml as well that I want to add. For this example, I just kept it simple to full strings

Comment: Actually if I use this it works
MyPattern = re.compile('|'.join(Ports))
But I want to add word boundary to each of the regexes. Any idea how I can modify the above to add word boundary? Thanks...

Comment: The word boundry \b doesn't work if the string is ending with "]". So instead of "\b", the following regex works: re.compile(r'(?: |^)(?:%s)(?=[. ]|$)' % '|'.join(Ports))

This is essentially looking for space/newline and space/endofline instead of \b. 

Thanks all for your inputs!